# How to override ClearIndicator's onClick to blur control on clear in react-select?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-select

I want to blur (remove focus from) the control field in `react-select` soon as the `ClearIndicator` button is clicked.

I tried using a custom ClearIndicator component and defining an `onClick` handler for it but that doesn't seem to affect the onClick behaviour of the clear button.

Is there a way I can override or modify the onClick behaviour of the ClearIndicator button so I can call the `blur()` method when the Clear button gets clicked?

The code I tried is given below.

```
// react-select main component

<Select
  components={{ ClearIndicator }}
  isSearchable
  isClearable
 />
```

```
// custom clear button

export const ClearIndicator = (props: any) => {
  const {
    children = <>clear</>,
    getStyles,
    innerProps: { ref, ...restInnerProps },
  } = props;

  const handleClearValue = () => {
    ref.blur();
  };

  return (
    <div
      {...restInnerProps}
      ref={ref}
      style={getStyles("clearIndicator", props)}
      onClick={handleClearValue}
    >
      <div style={{ padding: "0px 5px" }}>{children}</div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Codesandbox link:
https://codesandbox.io/s/solitary-voice-0qmvc?file=/example.jsx

Answer (score 4):

I have edited your code and moved the actions taken on the select itself directly in the **default** component (where **select** is located):

```
export default () => {
  
  const selectRef = useRef(null);
  const blurOut = () => {
    selectRef.current.blur();
  }
  return (
    <Select
      ref={selectRef}
      onChange={blurOut}
      defaultValue={colourOptions[1]}
      options={colourOptions}
      components={ClearIndicator }
      isClearable
    />
  );
};
```

Also, remove `onClick` from the `ClearIndicator` element:

```
const ClearIndicator = (props) => {
  const {
    children = <CustomClearText />,
    getStyles,
    innerProps: { ref, ...restInnerProps }
  } = props;


  return (
    <div
      {...restInnerProps}
      ref={ref}
      style={getStyles("clearIndicator", props)}
      
    >
      <div style={{ padding: "0px 5px" }}>{children}</div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

### Tip:

Never `useState` to store a reference to an element. Use `useRef` - [find more here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the `useRef` tip! I've modifed the original code to use that instead: [New Codesandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/solitary-voice-0qmvc?file=/example.jsx)

However, this still doesn't solve the original problem. The code you gave blur's the control field when an option is selected from the dropdown. But when you click on "clear", you can still type in the control field without clicking anything which means it's still focused and didn't get blurred on click of clear.